# Adal js Library - this.adalService.acquireToken method giving "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout" on first time login

Tags: angularjs, adal, adal.js, adal4j

Though there are some link related to this questions but I did't find any relevant answer, So hoping someone will answer this time.

Here is the scenario, In my Angular Application I am using **adal-angular4** which is wrapper over **Adal.js**

**Issue** : **this.adalService.acquireToken** method during only first time login. I am getting timeout error but after login if i will do page refresh then **this.adalService.acquireToken** method working properly and the interesting part are following.

1. Issue is only coming in deployed environment **not in the localhost.**
2. Error "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout" **coming only sometimes when network is slow or random times**.

[image]

Here is my request interceptor service

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse
| HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
if (req && req.params instanceof CustomAuthParams && req.params.AuthNotRequired) {
  return this.handleAuthentication(req, next, null);
} else {
  if (!this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
    console.log(req, 'Cannot send request to registered endpoint if the user is not authenticated.');
  }
  var cachedToken = this.adalService.getCachedToken(environment.authSettings.clientId);
  console.log('cachedToken', cachedToken);
  if (cachedToken) {
    return this.adalService.acquireToken(resourceURL).timeout(this.API_TIMEOUT).pipe(
      mergeMap((token: string) => {
        return this.handleAuthentication(req, next, token);
      })
    ).catch(err => { console.log('acquire token error', err); return throwError(err) })
  } else {
    this.adalService.login();
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after struggling for 1 to 2 days I have found the root cause. So posting this answer so that it will help others.

**adal-angular4** library is using **1.0.15** version of **adal-angular** which is old version where default timeout for **loadFrameTimeout** is **6 seconds** and in this version there is no configuration to increase the **loadFrameTimeout**. please see below link

[Adal configurations](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/Config-authentication-context)

Now during first time login there are many steps happens.

1. After authentication, application redirect to configured URI by azure AD, By appending **ID and Access token** in the reply URL.
2. Then Library set all these token in the **local storage or session storage** depends on the configuration.
3. Then your applications loads and start making calls to webapi. Now here is the interesting things was happening, for each request I am calling **acquireToken** method against webapi application, So if network is slow **acquireToken** calls will give timeout error since **6 second** is not enough sometimes. But for some of the API it will able to get the token.
4. Now on first call acquireToken method takes time but for subsequent request it takes token from the **cache** if it is available, so timeout error was coming only for first time not after that.

So, In this library for now there is no way to increase the **loadFrameTimeout** so I used 
[Angular5 warpper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5) which is using **1.0.17** version of **adal-angular** where we can increase **loadFrameTimeout** which solved my issue.